# How do I reset an input field on 'Enter' keyUp in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I am creating an input that adds to a list of tags rendered below the input. I would like the input to push the tag to the list when 'Enter' is pushed while the user is focused on the input field. The field then resets to blank or "", and the user can add another tag in the same fashion.

The problem I am having is that after the value gets reset to a blank string, any time I try to grab the value of the input an empty string is returned.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    const [listOfOptions, addOption] = React.useState([])

    let newOption = () =>{
        let addField = document.getElementById('addOption')
        let grabText = addField.value;
        console.log('Grabtext ='+ grabText)
        addOption([...listOfOptions, grabText])
        addField.reset();
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        document.getElementById('addOption').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
                        newOption()
            }}
        );    }, [listOfOptions])
```

Comment: I feel like there's no reason to be using any dom apis here. Why not put the keyup listener on the react element and use state for values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, taking into consideration the earlier suggestions, thanks for the help, would then be the below:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const [listOfOptions, addOption] = React.useState([])


const handleFormValueChange = (event) => setValue(event.target.value);

    let newOption = (event) => {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            addOption([...listOfOptions, value]);
            setValue('');
        }
    }

<input value={value} onChange={(event) => handleFormValueChange(event)} onKeyUp={(event)=>newOption(event)} id="addOption" />
```

This solution uses the Enter keydown to submit and reset the value, whilst modifying only React's virtual DOM.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid directly manipulating the DOM in React. Let React's Virtual DOM handle that.

You can store the value of the form in state and then on submit it resets the state to ''.

Something like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const handleFormValueChange = (event) => setValue(event.target.value);

const resetFormValue = () => setValue('');

<input type="text" value={value} onChange={(event) => handleFormValueChange(event)} />
<input type="submit" onSubmit={resetFormValue} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `addOption` is an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>`, it should not have `reset()` method. Modify `.value` instead

```
addField.value = "";
```

Don't forget to detach eventListener on this component dismount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const element = document.getElementById("addOption");
  const listener = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      newOption();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  element.addEventListener("keyup", listener);

  return () => element.removeEventListener("keyup", listener);
}, [listOfOptions]);
```

Also please avoid directly modifying `DOM` directly to a React rendered element, as it may disrupt React render process.

Instead, use a state library such as [this](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated) or [event library](https://github.com/Kelerchian/florcky)

**Edit**:

You should avoid manipulating DOM directly as told in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60401293/5381781) by [David Caldwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6558312/david-caldwell)